# Getting ctx for a specific webpart

Tags: 2007, javascript

My goal is to replace a text in a specific column by an icon using only javascript.

```
function ReplaceTxtbyIcn(targetWP, targetColumn, pat, urlname)
{
  var table = document.getElementById(targetWP);
  if (table != null)
     {
      var tbody = table.childNodes[0];
      var trs = tbody.childNodes;
      for (var i=1;i<trs.length;i++)
      { 
        var tdVal = trs[i].childNodes[targetColumn].outerText;
        if( tdVal == pat)
       {
         $(trs[i].childNodes[targetColumn]).text('');
         $(trs[i].childNodes[targetColumn]).append('<img src="******SomeURL******'+urlname+'.png"  alt="'+pat+'"/>');
       }    
     }
    }
};
```

For targetWP it should be equal to ctx.listName + "-" + ctx.view
My problem here is how to get the ctx for the specific webpart using the id of the webpart.
I am on Sharepoint 2007, any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function could be used for retrieving Context Info by Web Part ID

```
//Retrieve Context Info By WebPartID
function getContextInfo(webPartID)
{
        //Resolve ViewId from WebPartId
        var strViewId=webPartID.toUpperCase();
        //Retrieve Context Info Number
        var ctxNum=g_ViewIdToViewCounterMap[strViewId]; 
        if (ctxNum==null)
            return null;
        //Retrieve Client Context by Number  
        var ctxT=window["ctx"+ctxNum];
        return ctxT;
}
```

### Usage

```
//Retrieve Context Info for Latest Documents Web Part 
function loadLatestDocumentsContextInfo()
{ 
    var curctx = getContextInfo('{d8e2098c-170d-4114-92f1-95619f716911}');
    console.log(curctx);
}


_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('loadLatestDocumentsContextInfo');
```

> Note: Web Part ID could be identified on page as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840224/how-do-i-find-the-id-of-a-web-part-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Tested with SharePoint 2010 only

Comment: Perfect, thank You much! I'll add that strViewId looks like "{86AD4EDF-223E-4B83-B261-DDBBE25F46C1}"